# Tap to retry in ionic1

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework

How can I  applied the tap to retry functionality like Gmail in my Ionic 1 App. I want to apply this throughout my app.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You need to use [ionic toast](https://market.ionic.io/plugins/ionictoast) plugin to create notifications like this.

Install it with bower or npm and then use it like this.

```
$scope.showToast = function(){
<!-- ionicToast.show(message, position, stick, time); -->
  ionicToast.show('This is a toast at the top.', 'bottom', true, 2500);
};
```

For network information use this [plugin](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-network-information)

use this [plugin](https://github.com/EddyVerbruggen/Toast-PhoneGap-Plugin) to get callback on toast click.

for latest version of Ionic, however, there is a built in native functionality for this feature [native ionic toast](https://ionicframework.com/docs/components/#toast)

Comment: How can I add "Retry" button to it? How can I check all the time if internet is available. Do I need to call Network Information plugin methods in some interval or there is some other way?

Comment: what is your ionic version?

Comment: any solution for this?

Comment: I have added two more links in the answer one plugin is an alternative toast which will give you callbacks on click and other will tell you about network connection. have a look at them.